Having trouble referencing list in PowerAutomate Desktop
I am trying to set a variable to the first item in a list. When I reference the list in the set variable value field like this %ColMap[0]% it always sets the variable as the string %ColMap[0]%.
I tried to have copilot do the same thing and it appears to use the exact same syntax as me but somehow yields the desired result (sets the variable to the first item in the list). What the heck is going on?
The first picture is what I put in the set variable dialogue box, the second is how it looks in the flow with the variable produced. The third picture is what copilot put in the set var box, the fourth is the copilot flow.
My Set Variable Box
My Flow
Copilot's Set Var box
Copilot's Flow
